# npm ERR! could not determine executable to run when running npx cap sync

Tags: npm, capacitor, npx

When I run `npx cap sync`, I get:

```
npm ERR! could not determine executable to run
```

Several questions have been asked about this error, but none is related to capacitor. I started getting the error today after installing 3 capacitor plugins.

Among the solutions I've researched online, none seems to work. I've done `npm install`, I've updated npm and node to their latest versions, some working solutions even suggest downgrading node, which I don't think is ideal. I've been stuck researching this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The solution was simply to [upgrade capacitor to its latest version](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/updating/3-0)

```
npm install @capacitor/cli@latest @capacitor/core@latest
```